# What is a reasonable model measurement for a binary classification on an imbalanced data set? Accuracy? ROC?

Tags: classification, measurement, accuracy, unbalanced-classes

We analyzed whether or not user comments contain customer needs or not. The comments are manually labeled by experts (comments with needs = 330, comments with no needs = 1600). We used different algorithms for classification (like Random Forests, Random Trees, Bayes Net, Naive Bayes) and different sampling methods (undersampling, oversampling, SMOTE) as well as 10-fold-cross-validation.

We are very happy with the precision and recall of different combinations, but we are struggling with finding a good/suitable/reasonable measurement for comparing the results. So far we would just go with accuracy, but it doesn't take a lot of things into account. Should we go with a ROC Analysis? Or is there another reasonable measurement for our models?

Comment: Area under the precision-recall curve is often more suitable for imbalanced problems, as they are more sensitive to differences between models that can appear minor in terms of area under the ROC curve. You can refer to the [seminal paper of Davis & Goadrich on the relationship between precision-recall and ROC curves](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/icml2006_DavisG06.pdf)  for more background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accuracy is not a great measure, particularly when dealing with highly imbalanced datasets. To see that, assume your negative set constitutes 99% of the population - then just by predicting that everyone is a negative you'll achieve 99% accuracy, but your predictions won't be helpful.

AUC (and potentially partial AUC, depending on your overall objective) would be a much better measure in this case. Note that the model with the best AUC might not necessarily be reflective of the "best" model in your case - it really depends on what you want to do with the data. For example, if you're going to choose a cutoff that only flags 300 comments, then you're only concerned with how the model performs on that subset, and you don't care too much about the other observations. That being said, in practice AUC would likely be a good comparison.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! We want to use the trained model to apply it to huge sets of (comment) data to automatically identify comments containing needs. Having this in mind, would you still go for AUC?